# Link to Cognito Forms not working

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to know how to get the link for sharing forms to my user, the actual link, not embed codes. I've tried to share via social network but the link that was shared wasn't for my form and the page just showed "404 not found".

Answer (score 1):

In further communications with Mr. Duke the core issue was the form had an availability start date set to a date in the future thus the form would not be available to social links.

Once he changed the availability start date to a date in the past the form became available.

Cognito Forms by default have no start or end dates but are optional properties that can be set.